# Finite generation of global sections of an invertible sheaf on a quasi-projective scheme

Tags: algebraic-geometry

Let $X$ be a projective scheme over a noetherian ring, $\mathcal F$ an invertible sheaf on $X$, and $U$ an arbitrary open subset of $X$.
Is $\Gamma(U,\mathcal F)$ a $\Gamma(U,\mathcal O_X)$-module of finite type?

Comment: Answered by Jason Starr here: http://mathoverflow.net/questions/240170/finite-generation-of-global-sections-of-an-invertible-sheaf-on-a-quasi-projectiv